# INSERT a record in XCountries only if X.CountryID not exists in XCountries without using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Retailers and RetailersCountries tables. In Retailers table I have CountryID. Now for each retailer in Retailers table, I have to insert a record in RetailersCountries if not exist . I can do this using cursor. But I want to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of doing what you describe. I can image you have some requirements for new keys and such but you can probably figure that out from here. If not please provide details on those requirements so we can help with that to.

```
SELECT cols
INTO RetailersCountries 
WHERE cols NOT IN (
    SELECT cols 
    FROM RetailersCountries)
```